# Error in getting access token using client_credentials and authorization_code grant_type

Tags: token

We need to consume API in Android application which requires access token. Tried client_credentials and authorization_code method to get the access token. 
Getting the following error for client_credentials:
"AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid.
Note: We are passing client_id,client_secret,scope and grant_type in the body of the request.
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:***
client_secret:***
scope:****

The second method which we tried "authorization_code" is returning 200 OK Response without any authorization token. 
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:***
client_secret:**
scope:
**redirect_uri:***
state:12345
response_type:code
response_mode:query

Any pointers on this will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should try passing scope too along with grant_type etc.
Try

```
    **'client_secret' : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'client_id':'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'scope':'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
    'grant_type':"client_credentials"**
```

Try with these parameters and see if it works.
Although in the documentation somewhere is recommended/options but you have to pass scope in the body along with other parameters.
Thanks